# Javascript: console.logs in function to html div as function executes

Tags: javascript

I want to show console log in html div. I am able to do that with below code.

```
var log = document.getElementById("logger")
 console.log = (function (method, log) {
        return function (text) {
            method(text);
            let msg = document.createElement('div');
            msg.textContent = text;
            log.appendChild(msg);
        };
 })(console.log.bind(console), log);
```

But console.log in functions does show in html div unless whole function execution is complete?

How can I show console logs in html div as function is executing (without waiting for function to complete its execution)?

In below example, I see logs in div after for loop execution gets complete.

```
function testfunction(){
    console.log('test function');
    for(let i=0; i<100000; i++){
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

I see updated logs in div in Inspect-> Elements and not on browser page.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  What do you mean by "as function is executing?"

Comment: function testfunction { console.log("1"); console.log("2"); someotherfunction();  } I want 1,2 to display in html div as soon it prints on console. with current code, html div shows 1,2 after testfunction execution gets complete.

Comment: Can you make an example that shows the problem you are having?  I tested this and I see the log messages in both the console and the div.  What is `someotherfunction()` doing?

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded.  Both your code and code the browser itself runs is in one thread.  What is your `testfunction()` or `someotherfunction()` doing?  Maybe you need to call one (or both of those) in a `setTimeout()` to allow the browser a second to run other code (like refreshing the DOM).

Comment: In below example, I see logs in div after for loop execution gets complete.   function testfunction(){     
          
              console.log('test function')
              for(let i=0;i<100000;i++){
                console.log(i)
              } 
      }

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Is my question clear with for loop example ?

Comment: @NishiP Yes, the example does help explain things.

Comment: `console.log()` shows logs at the console tab and you see divs in the element tab because in that console log function you've shown you're appending divs to the DOM

Comment: @Kakiz, you are right. But shouldn't it show immediately on browser page also as I am overriding default console log function ? In this example, It waits for loop to get completed and then prints  in div on browser page.

Answer (score 1):

give it some time to execute otherwise everything will be processed at the same time

```
function testfunction(){
    console.log('test function');
    for(let i=0; i<100000; i++){
        setTimeout(() => {
           console.log(i);
        }, i * 5)
    }
}
```